# UITabBar: iOS and Android

Tags: android, tabs

I am an iOS developer and still new to Android. I have a question, which is essentially a clarification question. The tabs for UITabBar on iOS, by default is at the bottom but for Android, it seems as though it is at the top by default, is this correct? If yes, is it possible to move the tab bar to the bottom rather than at the top? If yes, I would like to learn how and I will appreciate a reference to a tutorial which I can study for the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Pure Android design](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html):

> Other platforms use the bottom tab bar to switch between the app's views. Per platform convention, Android's tabs for view control are shown in action bars at the top of the screen instead. In addition, Android apps may use a bottom bar to display **actions** [not tabs] on a [split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar).